# Assynchronous serial comms: why does ReadFile() set the event in the OVERLAPPED struct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I have drawn on various sources to piece together some (multi-threaded) code to read and write from/to a serial port. It all works fine... except that the loop in the thread that does the reading from the serial port unintentionally does a busy wait. Essentially what happens repeatedly is:

- An event (created outside the read loop) is reset, and its handle used as the hEvent member in an OVERLAPPED struct.
- ReadFile() is passed the OVERLAPPED struct (among other parameters) and returns immediately
- WaitForSingleObject() waits on the event in the OVERLAPPED struct, but always returns immediately because the event is always set after the ReadFile()
- GetOverlappedResult() is then passed the same OVERLAPPED struct, returns successfully, but typically only reads 0 bytes

My expectation was that the whole point of the event was to signal when there is data available to read. But ReadFile() sets the event, and so what is the point? What am I missing?

The following stripped-back code demonstrates the issue on my system (I have COM3 connected). The full code quite happily reads and writes... but the reader suffers from the condition described above:

```
HANDLE portHandle = CreateFile( "COM3",
                                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                0,
                                NULL,
                                OPEN_EXISTING,
                                FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                                NULL );  // succeeds
HANDLE readerEvent = CreateEvent( 0, TRUE, FALSE, _T( "Rx Event" ) );  // succeeds
char buffer[ 200 ];
DWORD bytesRead;
OVERLAPPED reader;
memset( &reader, 0, sizeof( reader ) );
reader.hEvent = readerEvent;
ResetEvent( readerEvent );
ReadFile( portHandle, buffer, 200, &bytesRead, &reader );
if ( WaitForSingleObject( reader.hEvent, 2000 ) == WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
{
    // always true, never has to wait on the event.
}
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: You don't need to reset the event manually. `ReadFile` does that for you. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `ReadFile resets the event to a nonsignaled state when it begins the I/O operation.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it: the documentation for the ReadFile function contains this paragraph:

- When reading from a communications device, the behavior of ReadFile is determined by the current communication time-out as set and retrieved by using the SetCommTimeouts and GetCommTimeouts functions. Unpredictable results can occur if you fail to set the time-out values. For more information about communication time-outs, see COMMTIMEOUTS.

I was not using SetCommTimeouts() at all. Performing a GetCommTimeouts() and inspecting the results showed the port's settings were the values described in this paragraph from the COMMTIMEOUTS documentation:

- A value of MAXDWORD, combined with zero values for both the ReadTotalTimeoutConstant and ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier members, specifies that the read operation is to return immediately with the bytes that have already been received, even if no bytes have been received.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`WaitCommEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363479.aspx) function to wait on the event with a specific event mask. Code sample using CreateFile and WaitCommEvent: [Monitoring Communications Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363424.aspx).

Comment: Thanks - was not aware of that functionality either.