# WaitForMultipleObjects() does not return until buffer is full, unless I use Putty

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2017

I've got a child thread that calls WaitForMultipleObjects() and blocks waiting for, among other things, an incoming message over COM4. Attached to the other side of COM4 is a board sending a message once every five seconds.

The problem is, WaitForMultipleObjects() is only notified that a message was received when the read buffer I allocated for it is full, rather than becoming notified whenever a single message is transmitted.

The weird part is that this behavior changes if I connect to the board with putty, close putty, and then reopen my application - WaitForMultipleObjects() will thereafter return whenever a message is received, buffer filled or not. This behavior is preferable, and I would like to know what putty is doing so that I may have it enabled all the time.

I checked the DCB object returned from GetCommState() both with and without using Putty, and it doesn't appear that Putty is changing the structure in a way that I am not already doing.

Here is the code initializing the HANDLE object for the com port (referred to as "hCom"):

```
bool init(struct ReadComArg readComArg) {
    BOOL fSuccess;

    log(comPort);
    //  Open a handle to the specified com port.
    hCom = CreateFile(comPort,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,      //  must be opened with exclusive-access
        NULL,   //  default security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING, //  must use OPEN_EXISTING
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,      //  can't write in one thread while blocked for a read in another unless port is declared overlapped
        NULL); //  hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices

    if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        //  Handle the error.
        log("Failed to create hCom handle");
        return false;
    }

    DWORD lptEvtMask;
    fSuccess = GetCommMask(hCom, &lptEvtMask);
    if (!fSuccess) {
        log("GetCommMask failed");
        CloseHandle(hCom);
        return false;
    }
    fSuccess = SetCommMask(hCom, lptEvtMask);
    printAll(&lptEvtMask);

    //  Initialize the DCB structure.
    DCB dcb;
    SecureZeroMemory(&dcb, sizeof(DCB));
    dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);

    
    //  Build on the current configuration by first retrieving all current
    //  settings.
    /*fSuccess = GetCommState(hCom, &dcb);

    if (!fSuccess) {
        log("GetCommState failed");
        CloseHandle(hCom);
        return false;
    }
    */
    dcb.BaudRate = readComArg.baudRate;     //  115200  baud rate
    dcb.ByteSize = readComArg.dataBits;     //  8       data size, xmit and rcv
    /*
    dcb.Parity = readComArg.parity;      //  parity bit
    dcb.StopBits = readComArg.stopBits;    //  stop bit
    dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE;
    dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
    */
    fSuccess = SetCommState(hCom, &dcb);

    if (!fSuccess) {
        log("SetCommState failed");
        CloseHandle(hCom);
        return false;
    }

    //  Get the comm config again.
    fSuccess = GetCommState(hCom, &dcb);

    if (!fSuccess) {
        log("GetCommState failed");
        CloseHandle(hCom);
        return false;
    }
    log("Serial Port successfully reconfigured");

    hFile = CreateFileW(fileName,  // name of the write
        FILE_APPEND_DATA,          // open for appending
        0,                          // no sharing
        NULL,                      // default security
        OPEN_ALWAYS,               // open existing file or create new file 
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,     // normal file
        NULL);                     // no attr. template

    if (hFile == NULL) {
        log("Failed to create hFile handle");
        CloseHandle(hCom);
        return false;
    }

    PostMessage(readComArg.MainWindow, WM_THREAD_UP, 0, 0);
    return true;
}
```

Putty doesn't touch any of the DCB fields except DCBlength, BaudRate, ByteSize, Parity, and StopBits, and setting the fields that aren't these five to arbitrary values doesn't seem to affect the code's behavior, so I left the rest at zero.

Here is the main loop code:

```
void loop(struct ReadComArg readComArg) {
    //TODO: close all handles when function returns
    const unsigned long BUFFSIZE = 256;
    BYTE buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    DWORD bytesRead, bytesWritten, result;
    OVERLAPPED osReader;
    OVERLAPPED osWriter;
    HANDLE eventArray[4];
    eventArray[0] = readComArg.killEvent;
    eventArray[2] = readComArg.writeRequestEvent;

    BOOL continueLooping = true;
    BOOL fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
    BOOL fWaitingOnWrite = FALSE;

    while (continueLooping) {
        //There is no outstanding read request and we must create a new one:
        if (!fWaitingOnRead) {
            //First, check to make sure we haven't received a killEvent.
            result = WaitForSingleObject(readComArg.killEvent, 0); //returns immediately
            if (result == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                //received killEvent, exiting
                log("killEvent was signaled. Exiting loop");
                if (!ResetEvent(readComArg.killEvent))
                    log("failed to reset killEvent");
                break;
            }
            else if (result != WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
                //some error occured
                log("WaitForSingleObject returned an error");
                break;
            }
            //Otherwise, there was no kill request, continue as normal.
            //Attempt to create new read request
            osReader = { 0 };
            osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, NULL);
            //read event failed to allocate, return:
            if (osReader.hEvent == NULL) {
                log("failed to create readEvent");
                break;
            }
            eventArray[1] = osReader.hEvent;
            //Execute the asynchronous read:
            if (!ReadFile(hCom, buffer, BUFFSIZE, &bytesRead, &osReader)) {
                //The asynchronous read request succeeded and will be completed later:
                if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
                    log("Read request queued and pending");
                    fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;
                }
                //The asynchronous read request failed:
                else {
                    log("ReadFile returned an error");
                    CloseHandle(osReader.hEvent);
                    break;
                }
            }
            //The asynchronous read request succeeded and completed immediately:
            else {
                log("Read request queued and returned immediately");
                CloseHandle(osReader.hEvent);
                handleRead(readComArg, buffer, bytesRead);
            }
        }
        //We are waiting on an outstanding read request:
        else {
            //block until a signal arrives
            //if we are waiting on a write, then there is an additional signal we must block for
            if (fWaitingOnWrite) {
                log("blocking for kills, reads, writeRequests, and writeResponses.");
                result = WaitForMultipleObjects(4, eventArray, FALSE, INFINITE);
            }
            else {
                log("blocking for kills, reads, and writeRequests. No outstanding write Request.");
                result = WaitForMultipleObjects(3, eventArray, FALSE, INFINITE);
            }
            continueLooping = false;
            switch (result) {
                //The killEvent handle received a signal. This has priority over every other signal.
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                    log("Received killEvent. Exiting loop");
                    if (!ResetEvent(readComArg.killEvent))
                        log("failed to reset killEvent");
                    break;

                //The com port handle received a signal
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0+1:
                    log("received signal");
                    //Unsuccessful read
                    if (!GetOverlappedResult(hCom, &osReader, &bytesRead, FALSE)) {
                        log("GetOverlappedResult returned an error");
                        break;
                    }
                    //Successful read, continue looping
                    log("Outstanding read request fulfilled");
                    handleRead(readComArg, buffer, bytesRead);
                    fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
                    CloseHandle(osReader.hEvent);
                    continueLooping = true;
                    break;

                //The writeRequestEvent handle received a signal. Create an asynchronous write request:
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2:
                    //reset writeRequestEvent signal.
                    if (!ResetEvent(readComArg.writeRequestEvent)) {
                        log("failed to reset writeRequestEvent");
                        break;
                    }
                    //attempt to create writeResponseEvent:
                    osWriter = { 0 };
                    osWriter.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, NULL);
                    if (osWriter.hEvent == NULL) {
                        log("failed to create writeResponseEvent");
                        break;
                    }
                    eventArray[3] = osWriter.hEvent;
                    //execute the asynchronous write:
                    if (!WriteFile(hCom, readComArg.writeBuffer, readComArg.numCharsToWrite, &bytesWritten, &osWriter)) {
                        //The asynchronous write request succeeded and will be completed later:
                        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
                            log("Write request queued and pending");
                            fWaitingOnWrite = true;
                            continueLooping = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        //The asynchronous write request failed:
                        else {
                            log("WriteFile returned an error");
                            CloseHandle(osWriter.hEvent);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //The asynchronous write request succeeded and completed immediately
                    else {
                        log("Write request queued and returned immediately");
                        CloseHandle(osWriter.hEvent);
                        continueLooping = true;
                        PostMessage(readComArg.MainWindow, WM_THREAD_SENT, 0, 0);
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                //The writeResponseEvent handle received a signal
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0+3:
                    //Unsuccessful write
                    if (!GetOverlappedResult(hCom, &osWriter, &bytesWritten, FALSE)) {
                        log("GetOverlappedResult returned an error");
                        break;
                    }
                    //Successful write, continue looping
                    PostMessage(readComArg.MainWindow, WM_THREAD_SENT, 0, 0);
                    log("Outstanding write request fulfilled");
                    fWaitingOnWrite = FALSE;
                    CloseHandle(osWriter.hEvent);
                    continueLooping = true;
                    break;

                // Error in WaitForMultipleObjects()
                default:
                    log("WaitForMultipleObjects returned an error");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    CancelIo(hCom);
    if(fWaitingOnRead)
        CloseHandle(osReader.hEvent);
    if (fWaitingOnWrite)
        CloseHandle(osWriter.hEvent);
}
```

I am not very familiar with StackOverflow ettiquette, so if there is something incorrect with how I am asking my question, I apologize in advance and will correct it as soon as I am able. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138067/assynchronous-serial-comms-why-does-readfile-set-the-event-in-the-overlapped seems relevant; I don't want to mark it as a dupe because it's not really the same question, but have a look at the accepted answer and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You were correct!
Different symptoms, same cause.
Putty was setting member "ReadIntervalTimeout" of the commtimeout object to 1. Doing the same instantly fixed my problem